# Counting the filtered values in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

```
col1  col2   col3
0     14     37
10    29     49
20    30     40
```

I want to know the number of filtered values only on single column.Such as how many numbers are greater than 45 in column 3.
I tried

```
a = df["col3"] <= 45
a.sum()
```

But the out was 0.
(This is an example of the actual data I am working on.My actual data has 10.000 rows and 100 columns)

Comment: Using your sample dataframe, and running your sample code, `a.sum()` returned 2 (because 37 and 40 are both less than 45), so there's no problem there it seems.

Comment: Not reproducible. I get `2`.

Comment: Strange.I keep getting zero.Is there another way to do this?Maybe I can try that

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it would be:

```
len(df[df['col3'] <= 45])
```

Comment: Or an even better (and faster, probably) way: `df['col2'].le(45).sum()`

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {"col1": [0, 10, 20], "col2": [14, 29, 30], "col3": [37, 49, 40]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
df_filter = df[(df["col3"] <= 45)]
print("col3 sum\n",df_filter["col3"].sum()) # col3 data sum


print("---"*50)
print("all columns sum\n",df_filter.sum())# all data sum
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).